# How to get annotated attributes in a template from a DetailView?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset, django-annotate

I'm working on a small e-commerce. For a model 'Product' I keep track of the stock using a Custom Manager and a method called `Products.objects.with_stock()` that uses annotations (I'm required to do so, there's no way I can add a stock attribute in Product)

In a ListView of all the products, it's pretty straightforward to add the stock, to access it from a template:

```
# app/views.py
class ProductListView(ListView):
   ...
   def get_stock(self, obj):
        return obj.stock

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().with_stock()
```

And then in the template I just call it:

```
<!-- templates/home.html-->
{% for product in products %}
   <p> Stock: {{product.stock}} <p>
{% endfor %}
```

**How do I perform something similar for a DetailView?**

Given that a DetailView gets a particular object instance, where or how do I run something similar to what I did in the ListView? Where do I run that query method that affects all objects as a whole, so that then I can access it in the same way from the template?

Answer (score 0):

It couldn't be simpler: just do the same in the DetailView:

```
# app/views.py
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
   ...
   def get_stock(self, obj):
        return obj.stock

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().with_stock()
```

Comment: I was assuming that I couldn't use the "get_queryset(self)" method on a DetailView.